# How To Remove Empty Rows In JTable Java

Tags: java, swing

I am selecting records from the database and its showing some empty records in the JTable Along with the records I am not been able to filter records with table .

Here are some empty records which is in the image [image: Empty Records]

```
public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){

    ArrayList<User> usersList=new ArrayList<User>();
   Connection connection=getConnection();
    String query="SELECT * FROM info";
    Statement myState;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
    myState=connection.createStatement();
    rs=myState.executeQuery(query);

    User user;
    while(rs.next()){
            user=new User(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("fname"),rs.getString("lname"),rs.getInt("age"));
            usersList.add(user);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ep){                        
        ep.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usersList;
}
```

I am populating these records in JTable with this function which is given below.

```
public void ShowUsersinJTable(){


    ArrayList<User> uList=getUsers();
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    Object[] row=new Object[4];
    for(int i=0;i<uList.size();i++){


        row[0]=uList.get(i).getId();
        row[1]=uList.get(i).getFname();
        row[2]=uList.get(i).getLname();
        row[3]=uList.get(i).Age();
          model.addRow(row);
   }
}
```

Comment: so you want to only display as many rows as many records you get from db?

Comment: I want to show the records which are only in the database . Its also showing some empty records

Comment: the way you did it seems about right, i also did something similar, besides the fact i clear the table before i add new content. also id try to initialize a new row object every for every new record

Comment: can you point it out where i should i make edit in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the code seems about right try changing your code to this:

```
ArrayList<User> uList=getUsers();
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
for(int i=0;i<uList.size();i++){
    Object[] row=new Object[4];

    row[0]=uList.get(i).getId();
    row[1]=uList.get(i).getFname();
    row[2]=uList.get(i).getLname();
    row[3]=uList.get(i).Age();
      model.addRow(row);
}
```

also you can delete all rows before filling the table (only needed if table was filled with data)

```
for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    model.removeRow(i);
}
```

please tell me if it has worked, so i can help you further if needed

Comment: Is it necessary to recreate a new array here ? Never try it like OP is doing it but I guess the JTableModel was simply using the array to create his own cells, without keep the reference of the array. But this seems safer like this.

Comment: i used some of my old code to produce this. might not be necessary but i never tried

Comment: If you have a `DefaultTableModel`, the most efficient way to remove all rows is `setRowCount(0)`.

Comment: Removing all rows before adding the data did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

The default number of rows of the jTable in netbeans is four. So you can remove this by going to jTable properties -> model -> Rows.

[image]

[image]

Or, you can set rowCount to be zero before adding rows in the table like this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```